# SQL String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to search the max ID in the database, then increment it by 1 for each new entry as shown below:

```
var query2 = dbb.Database.SqlQuery<patient_visit>("SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(pvid, 3, 10) AS int)) FROM patient_visit");

            if (query2 != null)
            {
                objDetails.pvid = query2.ToString();
                objDetails.pvid += 1;
                objDetails.pvid = "PV" + objDetails.pvid;
            }

string sql = "INSERT INTO patient_visit (pvid,paid) " +
                         "VALUES('" + objDetails.pvid + "', '" + paid + "')";
```

But when i try to insert it in the database, it gives out error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

I've tried running the query in SQL Server and checked the value of 'pvid', it is 10 so after i include 'PV' to the integer pvid, it should be 12. So it should be fine, but why did i get that error? Please can anyone help me?

```
[Key]
    [MaxLength(20), MinLength(12)]
    public string pvid { get; set; }
```

When i replace the pvid with hard code ID, it works just fine. Why is this happening?

P/S: I know its not advisable to simply concatenate the input data with the query, but i've also tried querying using parameterized query but it gives same error.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO patient_visit (pvid,paid) " +
                         "VALUES(@pvid, @paid)";
List<SqlParameter> parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@pvid", objDetails.pvid));
parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@paid", paid));
SqlParameter[] parameters = parameterList.ToArray();
dbb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
```

Comment: can you please tell us why you are using a string pvid and increment by 1 where you can use an autoincrement field?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I'm using SQL Server 2012 for my database. I'm not really that familiar with it, can it be done with SQL Server 2012? How?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Field length of the column you are trying to put the data into.

I have had this problem before where the column was varchar(10)  and I was trying to concatenate two char strings of 6 characters each.  Making them 12 characters long.   2 longer than the target field.

Your problem might be similar.

Comment: How to check the field length?

Comment: @Nurul: you look at the **definition** of the column in the table, and before the insert happens, when you debug through, you check the **length of the strings** that you're passing in as values.....

Comment: @marc_s where exactly do i check that? In the Locals console in Visual Studio or in SQL server? Sorry i'm so clueless about this :(

Comment: @Nurul: you have to check the **length** of the columns - as they are defined in the SQL Server table - in SQL Server Management Studio. That tells you how long each string can be - at most. Then, when you **debug** your code in Visual Studio and you come to the point where the data should be inserted, check **in Visual Studio**, in the "Locals" or by just hovering the mouse over the variables, just how long each string **really is** - at least one of them will be **longer than the maximum allowed** as defined by the table - that's what this error says

Comment: @marc_s When i hover to the pvid, I couldn't see the exact value, it just shows the query string that is used in the search query, _"PVSELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(pvid, 3, 10) AS int)) FROM patient_visit1"_

Comment: @marc_s i'm not sure if its useful but at the Locals, under parameterList, for pvid(which is the incremental id generated through query), i see that the size is 69; whereas paid is correct 10. Pvid is supposed to be 12 in total, including the 'PV' at the front. Is it my query that is the cause of the problem?